# Sample based inversion of the Radon transform

Tags: pr.probability, inverse-problems

I have a classic tomography problem in which I would like to infer the internal density $p_0: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ from external Radon projections. The internal density however is viewed as a probability density function, and the Radon projections of $p_0$ are given in terms of samples from the Radon projection.

I recall having seen a paper which deals with such a sample based tomography problem, but I cannot find it anymore. I am glad for any hints and references on this problem.

Comment: I think you are looking for Bayesian methods for inverse problems; there are several groups working on this topic in connection with tomography, for example Samuli Siltanen (to give only one name).

Comment: They do employ Bayesian methods, but nevertheless that is definitely not the problem that I articulated in my question.